# can i run a group by statement within stored procedure and return the output as variable

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Hi All, 
 i am a nub to mysql and i am experimenting with stored procedure, i have written a script to calculate count of Respondent id, for now stored procedure returns a cumulative number however i would like resultant grouped by each city. when i attempt that i get an error message  stating "Result consisted of more than one row error"

Note: i am aware that i can query using where statement for each city however that method is in-efficient as i have to manually key in each distinct city name hence i am looking for alternatives to efficiently tackle this

any help would be greatly appreciated

regards
Sri

### Stored Procedure code

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS `Total_grpby`$$
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE
 `total_grpby
`(
OUT ex_total INT 
)

BEGIN
SELECT COUNT(rsp_id) As total INTO ex_total
 FROM test.`jnk_test`
 GROUP BY Dmc_Cty;
END$$
```

### desired output

```
dmc_cty    Total
Chennai    337
Delhi      263
Gurgaon    53
Hyderabad  406
Mumbai     482
Noida      464
Pune       522
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, it's not possible in MySql.
`OUT ex_total INT` declares a variable of type INT. 
The type `Int` can hold **one - and only one value** - it is a scalar variable.
However your query returns many values, not one. 
To store many values you need something like an array, or a collection.
Unfortunately, MySql doesn't support array nor collection datatypes, so in MySql you cannot store many values in one variable and return them as OUT parameter from the procedure.
This is possible in other databases, like PostgreSQL, Oracle, SQL-Server, they support collection datatypes.
In MySql, an ordinary SELECT (without INTO clause), which is execuded in the procedure, creates a resultset and returns it from the procedure to the client.
Unfortunately MySql is not able to read this resultset - for example if you call a procedura A, that returns a resultset, from another procedure B, then the procedure B is not able to retrieve data from the resultset returned by the procedure A.
This resultset can be read only by some clients, for example JDBC or ODBC connectors, SQLPlus or MySQLWorkbench etc.